# Предложение "Делать было нечего" - односоставное или двусоставное? И где подлежащее и сказуемое?

Tags: синтаксис

Какое предложение "Делать было нечего" - безличное, безлично-инфинитивное или двусоставное?

Answer (score 1):

Если в Ваших вариантах есть безлично-инфинитивное, то это как раз оно и есть.

*Делать было нечего*. Признаки налицо: **есть связка** в прош.времени и **модальное значение** невозможности действия в форме отрицательного местоимения.

Подробнее см.: КиберЛенинка: https://cyberleninka.ru/article/n/bezlichno-infinitivnye-predlozheniya-v-sovremennom-russkom-yazyke

Можно почитать здесь: Чжан Б., Покровская Е. А. Вопрос о соотношении инфинитивных и безличных предложений в отечественной лингвистике // Молодой ученый. — 2015. — №24. — С. 1167-1170. — URL  https://moluch.ru/archive/104/24459/

Comment: Спасибо! Просто именно здесь видела ответ на подобный вопрос, где такое предложение было названо двусоставным, и я засомневалась...